# Convert seconds to hh:mm:ss,fff format in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, windows-7-x64

I have a string representing a time in seconds and milliseconds. I want to convert it to a string in the format "hh:mm:ss,fff".

My solution still has the flaw that hours less than 10 are shown with one decimal instead of two:

```
PS> $secs = "7000.6789"
PS> $ts =  [timespan]::fromseconds($s)
PS> $res = "$($ts.hours):$($ts.minutes):$($ts.seconds),$($ts.milliseconds)"
PS> $res
PS> 1:56:40,679
```

What is the right way to achieve this? I'm sure there is a more elegant way with `-f` and datetime.

Comment: Does `$res.ToString()` not fill your requirements? It does skip milliseconds if there are no relevant digits and it does append days if the hours would otherwise be higher than 23, which might not suit you. If that doesn't work, look into the `TimeSpan.ToString(string)` method, which takes a format string. The format string can either be a [standard timespan format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372286(v=vs.110).aspx) or a [custom timespan format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 48, accepted):

In PowerShell 4.0

```
$s = "7000.6789"
$ts =  [timespan]::fromseconds($s)
("{0:hh\:mm\:ss\,fff}" -f $ts)
```

Output: `01:56:40,679`

---

In PowerShell 2.0

```
$s = "7000.6789"
$ts =  [timespan]::fromseconds($s)
"{0:hh:mm:ss,fff}" -f ([datetime]$ts.Ticks)
```

Output: `01:56:40,679`

---

And to go back the other way...

```
$text = "01:56:40,679"
$textReformat = $text -replace ",","."
$seconds = ([TimeSpan]::Parse($textReformat)).TotalSeconds
$seconds
```

Output: `7000.679`

Comment: Thank you andyb, this works very well! (I was so free and inserted the full example, feel free to roll back). How would an example look for the complete reverse of this? For example from `01:56:40,697` to `7000.6789`

Comment: The PowerShell V2 solution worked for some of my scenarios, but for durations of >= 13 hours, the hh field returns 01-12.

Comment: Thanks @RegisteredUser. I've modified the format strings to use the 24-hour version.

Comment: For your PowerShell 4.0 solution, I don't think the format string can include uppercase 'H' because this *results in an error*.  (Probably 2016-06-16 edit?) Changing it to lowercase 'h' (`"{0:hh\:mm\:ss\,fff}"`) doesn't result in an error but I'm guessing accuracy of timespan format string will be limited to 12 hours or less.  The error in PowerShell 4.0 is:  `Error formatting a string: Input string was not in a correct format.. At line:1 char:1 + ("{0:HH\:mm\:ss\,fff}" -f $ts)`

Comment: Yes, @JasDev, I think you are right. It seems the formatting logic for timespan does not support HH. I will revert back to 'hh'.

Answer (score 14):

You could just use the `ToString` method on the TimeSpan object and specify the format you want to use. Either use one of the [standard timespan formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372286%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or use a [custom timespan format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). For example, the following custom format gives the output you want:

```
$ts =  [timespan]::fromseconds("7000.6789")
$ts.ToString("hh\:mm\:ss\,fff")
```

This will output

```
01:56:40,679
```

*Update: Updating to provide functions working in PowerShell v2*

The above solution works well in PowerShell v4, but not in v2 (since the `TimeSpan.ToString(string)` method wasn't added until .NET Framework 4).

In v2 I guess you'll have to either create the string manually (like you are doing in the question) or doing an ordinary `ToString()` and manipulate the string. I suggest the former. Here's a function which works fine for that:

```
function Format-TimeSpan
{
    PARAM (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
        [TimeSpan]$TimeSpan
    )

    #Current implementation doesn't handle days.

    #By including the delimiters in the formatting string it's easier when we contatenate in the end
    $hours = $TimeSpan.Hours.ToString("00")
    $minutes = $TimeSpan.Minutes.ToString("\:00")
    $seconds = $TimeSpan.Seconds.ToString("\:00")
    $milliseconds = $TimeSpan.Milliseconds.ToString("\,000")

    Write-Output ($hours + $minutes + $seconds + $milliseconds)
}
```

Testing it using

```
$ts =  [timespan]::fromseconds("7000.6789")

Format-TimeSpan -TimeSpan $ts
$ts | Format-TimeSpan
```

Yields the following output:

```
01:56:40,679
01:56:40,679
```

Comment: Thank you Robert, I wasn't aware that the `TimeSpan.ToString(string)` was added later.

Answer (score 5):

One line conversion :

```
[timespan]::fromseconds(354801857.86437).tostring()
```

return `4106.12:04:17.8640000`