# How to add durations in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have two durations in my code. And I want to add them to get the total duration.

Many code examples add some durations to a date, but I have here two durations.

```
$startOfAnalysis = $(Get-Date)
#Analysis code here
$analysisDuration = $(Get-Date) - $startOfAnalysis
$totalAnalysisTime = "{0:HH:mm:ss}" -f ([datetime]  $analysisDuration.Ticks)
$totalAnalysisTime #Outputs similar to 00:16:21

$startOfExecution = $(Get-Date)
#Execution code here
$executionDuration = $(Get-Date) - $startOfExecution
$totalExecutionTime = "{0:HH:mm:ss}" -f ([datetime]$executionDuration.Ticks)
$totalExecutionTime #Outputs similar to 00:13:39

#($totalAnalysisTime+$totalExecutionTime) How to add the two to get 00:30:00?
```

How do I sum it up to make it to 30 minutes, i. e. 00:30:00?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add two `TimeSpan` instances together directly, no need for conversion to `DateTime` and back:

```
$total = $executionDuration + $analysisDuration
```

Just like with a `DateTime` instance, you can now use the `-f` string format operator, but beware that you need to escape special characters:

```
'{0:hh\:mm\:ss}' -f $total
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two options.

First one:
Convert your time back to seconds and then sum them up. Like that:

```
$Time1 = "01:56:40"
$textReformat1 = $Time1 -replace ",","."

$Time2 = "01:56:40" 
$textReformat2 = $Time2 -replace ",","."

$seconds = ([TimeSpan]::Parse($textReformat1)).TotalSeconds + ([TimeSpan]::Parse($textReformat2)).TotalSeconds


$TimeSpan = [timespan]::fromseconds($seconds)
("{0:HH\:mm\:ss}" -f [DateTime]$TimeSpan.Ticks)
```

And option two (the simple one):

Just calculate everything together before you convert them to a string. Something like that:

```
("{0:HH\:mm\:ss}" -f ([datetime]$analysisDuration.Ticks + $executionDuration.Ticks))
```

**Credits** to:
[Convert seconds to hh:mm:ss,fff format in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21842175/convert-seconds-to-hhmmss-fff-format-in-powershell)

For the example how to convert the timespan back to seconds